# Was Constantine's appearance based on Sting?

Tags: dc, behind-the-scenes, inspiration, vertigo-comics, constantine

Is there any evidence for this? I have encountered a person on a forum who claimed this to be true, but he failed to supply any proof. While I can notice some similarities, is this claim actually true?

To be clear, I mean his first appearance in print -  trench coat, blonde, tall. Same as his last portrayal by Matt Ryan.

Comment: I don't see why this should be voted closed, it's a legitimate question. The OP is asking for evidence, not our opinions.

Comment: Are you looking for his comic appearance or an appearance from somewhere else, like the 2005 movie?

Comment: His physical appearance in the 2005 movie was hardly even based on that of the character, forget Sting ;)

Comment: @Thunderforge  -  tall, blonde, trenchcoat... ring a bell?

Comment: @Gallifreian Honestly, I have no idea what Sting looks like. Guess I'm not in the right demographic.

Comment: @faintsignal: That was Neo, not John.

Comment: You have to admit Keanu did a darn good job though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes.
[Alan Moore has stated that in an interview](http://www.qusoor.com/hellblazer/Sting.htm): Steve Bissette and John Totleben, the artists drawing the Swamp Thing (that Alan Moore was writing at the time) sent him notes, expressing a desire to draw a character looking like Sting.

So he created the character John Constantine:

> **But I can state categorically that the character only existed because Steve and John wanted to do a character that looked like Sting**. Having been given that challenge, how could I fit Sting into Swamp Thing ? I have an idea that most of the mystics in comics are generally older people, very austere, very proper, very middle class in a lot of ways. They are not at all functional on the street. It struck me that it might be interesting for once to do an almost blue-collar warlock. Somebody who was streetwise, working class, and from a different background than the standard run of comic book mystics. Constantine started to grow out of that.

Comment: IIRC, one of the comics acknowledged it in a recursive manner by having a pair of girls sleep with Constantine because he "looked like Sting".